# Single protected member variable in base class VS Multiple private member variable in derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, private, protected

Scenario 1 : Single protected member variable in based class

```
class ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // common function
 protected:
  std::vector<uchar> m_image;
};

class MeanFilter : public ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // function that manipulates m_image
};

class MedianFilter : public ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // function that manipulates m_image
};
```

Scenario 2 : Multiple private member variable in derived class

```
class ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // common function
};

class MeanFilter : public ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // function that manipulates m_image
 private:
  std::vector<uchar> m_image;
};

class MedianFilter : public ImageFilter
{
 public:
  // function that manipulates m_image
 private:
  std::vector<uchar> m_image;
};
```

Which one is a better practice any why?

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/why-is-clean-code-suggesting-avoiding-protected-variables strongly advised against the use of protected variables, but MeanFilter obviously "is-a" ImageFilter and m_image will be needed for every kinds of image filter, and I couldn't think of a way to inherit member variable without using protected.

Comment: Why should an image filter own an image?

Comment: Use protected method for acess to m_image.

Comment: @n.m. This is just an example to illustrate the situation where there will be a variable that is common for it's derived class

Comment: Your examples don't work. Apart from the info "filter", there is no indication what these classes are supposed to do and how. In general, if a derived filter class is possible that doesn't use `m_image`, the vector doesn't belong in the baseclass.

Comment: A contrived example probably won't help you solve real problems. Do you have a real case? Anyway, "no protected data members" is a very good rule of thumb. If you don't use a data member in your base class, just don't put it there. If you do use it, consider replacing it by a pure virtual access function, because you don't really know how a derived class will want to implement it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What if the intention is any derived class is always going to have a m_image and use it?

Comment: Well, that's the reason your example is bad! It doesn't convey the info required to give an answer. Whether the general rules I mentioned apply is impossible to tell with the little info you provided.

Comment: @n.m. How about there is base class called "Dog", and derived class "Labrador" and "Husky", which "is-a" dog, and there will be a variable called "fur", which every kinds of dog will have, but just in different length and color. Should I make a single protected variable fur in Dog class or should I re-define "fur" as a private variable every single time in it's derived class?

Comment: It is hard to tell how such a "Dog" class could be used in real software. How about an example that deals with databases, GUIs, or compilers?

Comment: What would a Labrador-Husky-mix be represented with? Maybe there's no need for derivation at all, but rather a general dog class that has a flag for whether it has hair or not and such stuff? Seriously, it's pretty easy to give *some* guidelines, but those are soft guides and ignoring them will have little impact. Just try it out which you feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that by having a single member in the base class you can provide default implementation or even base class member functions that manipulate the image.

The dark side is however that you're placing restrictions on what the derived class could be and you're forcing them to be based on the image. For example a derived class that synthesize the image pixels based on some formula on the fly wouldn't fit this schema. Another example is a filter that needs not a single image but a vector of images instead: it would be forced to treat them differently (e.g. one in the base member and the others in the vector).

Comment: Is placing restrictions by having a default member for the derived class consider bad practice?